# Magento 2 how to restrict previous date in datepicker , for frontend detail page custom options

Tags: magento2, date, datepicker, product-detail-page, product-view-page

In Magento 2 how to restrict previous dates in datepicker ,in detail page customizable options,

Please help me out on this .

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your script add the following

```
$customId = <?php echo $product->getCustomId();?>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/calendar'
     ], function($, calendar) {
      $('#<?php echo $customId;?>').calendar({
            dateFormat: 'dd/M/Y',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '2000:2050',
            minDate: new Date(),
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: HI thanks for comment but in prodcut detail page custom options id is dynamic its keep on chnaging so what i need to do please help me

Comment: where did you write this script? Is it in phtml?

Comment: yes , iam trying in items.phtml(in magento-catalog) or footer.phtml

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento calendar library or jQuery date picker library then use below method

```
require([
         "jquery",
         "mage/calendar"
         ], function ($) {

    $('#example').datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                        timeFormat: "H:m:s",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        numberOfMonths: 1,
                        showsTime: true,
                        minDate: new Date()
                    });
});
```

In this, the minDate is the Date before which you want to restrict.

Comment: HI thanks for comment but in prodcut detail page custom options id is dynamic its keep on chnaging so what i need to do please help me

Comment: if the custom option's ID follows a pattern then use $('[id*="option_pattern"]') or use class instead of the Id